# PHPUnit can't find path, extra folders added by PhpStorm

Tags: phpunit, composer-php, phpstorm

I'm running phpunit and it gives me an error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MyApp\MyBundle\Tests\Units\Classes\Action\ActionTestCase' not found in /var/www/src/tests/src/MyApp/MyBundle/Classes/Action/KeywordTest.php on line 7
```

In that class is

```
5 use MyApp\MyBundle\Tests\Units\Classes\Action\ActionTestCase as TestCase;
6
7 class KeywordTest extends TestCase {
```

The thing I can't understand is, `ActionTestCase` exists, but at `MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Action\ActionTestCase`

When I use the autocomplete function of PhpStorm, it uses the path with the `\Tests\Units` part. That is the only path it finds, and if I double click in there it directs to the correct class. And yet PHPUnit doesn't find it.

Where is this extra path being added? In PhpStorm or Composer or somewhere else?

The composer.json file includes this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
}
,
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/tests"
    }
},
```

The phpunit.xml file includes this

```
<phpunit bootstrap="app/autoload.php">
```

Comment: Phpstorm scans all project files. Phpunit does not. Phpunit uses all classes which are available (when it is executed), that is often the autoloader. Check the Phpunit bootstrapping that you have your projects autoloader available when you run the test-suite via Phpunit.

Comment: Where's your ActionTestCase located on the filesystem?

Comment: @JakubZalas It's at `MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Action\ActionTestCase`

Comment: the full path from the top level of the project in PhpStorm is `src\tests\src\MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Action\ActionTestCase`

Comment: And how's your autoload-dev configured in composer.json?

Comment: @JakubZalas updated the question

Comment: The psr-0 autoloader already takes care of autoloading your tests since they're in the src folder. I suggest you move tests out of the src folder. Or at least remove the autoload-dev section as it's redundant (not sure how it will behave actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving tests out of src sounds like a good suggestion (regarding [*Jakub Zalas* comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950616/phpunit-cant-find-path-extra-folders-added-by-phpstorm#comment76914708_44950616)), you can better say if that is an option for you or not.

Regardless of that, the dev autoloader is not correctly configured for that path:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/tests"
    }
},
```

Would look for the file

```
src\tests\MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Action\ActionTestCase.php
```

but you have the file at

```
src\tests\src\MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Action\ActionTestCase.php
          ^^^
```

Adding the missing `src/` part should make it working:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/tests/src/"
    }
},
```

Don't forget to dump the autoload again:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

after you change the `composer.json`.

Comment: thanks, I never tried the dump-autoload before. I tried this and it still gives me the class found error. The thing is, tests in other folders do work so I think the problem arises from the \Tests\Units part that is being found in this particular case - I don't know where or why that is being inserted on autocomplete. I'll try moving the tests to its own folder out of src but I suspect it's unrelated to that because it works for other test classes.

Comment: Yeah I moved the tests to the same level as src, changed the composer file and dump-autoload and it gives me the same class not found.

Comment: Didn't know you have working auto-loaded tests (really? or are those files just included and don't need an autoloader ... ) in the same namespace and directory. Perhaps just a misunderstanding of the configuration, dump-autoload in composer re-creates the autoloader of composer, e.g. when you change composer.json for the autoloaders.

Comment: Not sure what happened but it now seems to work. Now when I use PHPStorm's auto complete it finds the location `tests\src\MyApp\MyBundle...`